# How can I distribute the service discovery tool consul to linux hosts?

Tags: service-discovery, consul

[Consul](http://www.consul.io/) isn't currently published in a package manager format. Whats a good way to distribute it across many systems and ensure its installed in a consistent manner?

Comment: // , I have this same sort of question, but in the more general sense of what to do with software "packaged" as a binary inside an archive. May I know what research you have done in advance of this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that you can easily create a package from the consul binary using [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm):

```
fpm --verbose -s dir -t rpm -n consul -v 0.4 --url=http://consul.io --vendor=HashiCorp  --description "A distributed service discovery tool" ./consul_/consul=/usr/local/bin/consul
```

That command will create an rpm file in your current working directory. You can also use 'deb' with the -t flag to create a deb package instead.

If you don't already have fpm installed, you can install it with rubygems:

```
gem install fpm
```

FPM requires the tools needed to create the package type you choose, so best to install this on a like system (Red Hat or Debain variant for RPM and DEB respectively)

Comment: // , Would this work for distribution to Debian, CEntOS 5 or CEntOS 6?

Comment: FPM builds packages for multiple distros, see https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm for more details

Answer (score 3):

Deliver it as a [docker](https://www.docker.com/) container.

The [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/) would:

1. wget the zip file, unzip it
2. Make directories for data and config
3. Add consul.json configuration file
4. Create volumes for the configuration and data
5. Expose consul port(s)
6. Define entrypoint

The Dockerfile would look approximately like this:

```
RUN wget 'https://dl.bintray.com/mitchellh/consul/0.3.1_linux_amd64.zip' -O consul.zip && unzip -d /usr/bin consul.zip 
RUN mkdir -p /opt/consul/data /opt/consul/config
ADD consul.json /opt/consul/config/
VOLUME ["/opt/consul/data","/opt/consul/config"]
EXPOSE 8500
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/consul", "agent", "-config-dir=/opt/consul/config"]
CMD ["-server", "-bootstrap"]
```

Comment: // , This only distributes it to/via Docker, though. I believe this sort of sidesteps the "across many systems" part of @wjimenez5271's question, doesn't it?

Comment: @NathanBasanese I don't know what you mean. If sidestep means that it fails, then no, it will succeed on every platform that supports docker. I think that is good. If you mean that the solution should be written in low-level primitives (wget/curl, unzip) available on all platforms, then why? If you mean it must be written directly on the native OS -- why? "This only distributes it to/via Docker" -- why would that disqualify this answer?

Comment: // , Docker *is* a platform, and any docker solution would be specific to the *docker* platform. This kind of thinking is yet another example of standards proliferation. I think we can agree that Docker (in its capacity as a standard systems platform only) at least creates *some* of the problem it attempts to solve, no? https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: // , It's a great resource saver and standardization tool where one can guarantee that it will run, no doubt.

Answer (score 3):

consul is a single binary, perfectly suited for easy (re-)distribution and handling.
Packaging as .deb is just a three-liner with fpm.

Prerequisite: install fpm with `gem install fpm`

Full working example for consul 0.6 (current version as of January 2016):

```
wget -N https://releases.hashicorp.com/consul/0.6.0/consul_0.6.0_linux_amd64.zip
unzip -o consul_0.6.0_linux_amd64.zip
fpm --force --verbose -s dir -t deb -n consul -v 0.6 \
  --url=http://consul.io --vendor=HashiCorp  \
  --description "A distributed service discovery tool" ./consul=/usr/local/bin/consul
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a puppet module (https://github.com/solarkennedy/puppet-consul) which can help with this. It pulls the binary from `dl.bintray.com` and also helps out with configuring the system.

Install a server, joining to 172.20.20.10. we are "expecting" a 3 node cluster, so this snippet will work for all three server nodes (even the first as long as it's the "172.20.20.10" copy)

```
class { 'consul': 
    join_cluster => '172.20.20.10',
    config_hash => {
        'datacenter' => 'dc1',
        'data_dir'   => '/opt/consul',
        'log_level'  => 'INFO',
        'node_name'  => $::hostname,
        'bind_addr'  => $::ipaddress_eth1,
        'bootstrap_expect' => 3,
        'server'     => true,
    }
}
```

that snippet will also work for the client agents (just flip the "server" bit to false.) The last step is to create a service definition and register it with the local consul client agent:

```
consul::service { "foo",
    tags           => ['service'],
    port           => 8080,
    check_script   => '/opt/foo-health-checker.sh',
    check_interval => '5s',
}
```

Here is an example Vagrantfile to build up a demo stack, complete with a 3 node consul cluster: https://github.com/benschw/consul-cluster-puppet

... and a blog post walking through how it was built: http://txt.fliglio.com/2014/10/consul-with-puppet/

Comment: // , Does not work on CEntOS 6 Puppet masters running Puppet 3.6. :( https://github.com/solarkennedy/puppet-consul/issues/317#issuecomment-279447461

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to reuse one of [the existing docker images](https://registry.hub.docker.com/search?q=consul).

e.g. [progrium/consul](https://github.com/progrium/docker-consul) is a great container designed to work in the Docker ecosystem

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in Ubuntu packages, I started maintaining a Launchpad PPA at https://launchpad.net/~bcandrea/+archive/ubuntu/consul. It currently targets LTS releases (12.04/14.04) which are the ones I need, but I might consider adding intermediate releases as well.

You can install it with the usual steps:

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:bcandrea/consul
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install consul consul-web-ui
```

If you want to make a Debian/Ubuntu package for it and distribute it yourself, you might want to look at my Makefile for creating the packages: https://github.com/bcandrea/consul-deb.

Comment: minus one: "I started maintaining", except they are not maintained.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. I had difficulties reproducing package builds, then (after an admittedly very long pause) I recently switched to using Docker and git-buildpackage and uploaded the latest version, v0.6.4. I guess the accepted solution is still the quickest way to get to a binary package, though.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative which only assumes that the linux target machines have ssh daemon running and that from the source machine you can ssh using keys:

Ansible can be installed on the source machine, then use a simple command line as described in http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_adhoc.html#file-transfer

> File Transfer   Here’s another use case for the /usr/bin/ansible
>   command line. Ansible can SCP lots of files to multiple machines in
>   parallel.
>
> To transfer a file directly to many servers:
>
> ```
> $ ansible atlanta -m copy -a "src=/etc/hosts dest=/tmp/hosts"
> ```

So assuming you already have the needed file `consul`, prepare a file containing the list of target machines. This is called `inventory` in ansible jargon - http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html

then `ansible my_linux_machines -m copy -a "src=consul dest=/usr/bin/consul"`

you can also have ansible download the zip, untar it and then copy. search "ansible untar"

Answer (score 0):

There is a multi-platform Ansible role that helps create a Consul cluster with clients:

https://github.com/brianshumate/ansible-consul

Another role of his can add Vault on top of Consul.